# Parse.com: Does PinInBackground() to Local DB save to the Cloud eventually?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, synchronization, cloud

I use the [Parse.com](https://parse.com) Cloud service in my Android app to sync data between devices.

I use the app mainly offline and use the local DB

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());
```

I would like to use `PinInBackground()` to store the data locally and sync once every day by hitting the sync button in my app.

Now if my app crashes or the device restarts - how do I know which objects are stored only locally so I can sync them with `Save()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pinInBackground()` will not save to the cloud eventually. The only action that does BOTH is `saveEventually()`, which will pin your objects locally if your network is down so that you can still query them even though you are still offline.

More in the [Parse Android guide](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-saving-objects-offline)